# Does declaring a result set with 'AS' key word create a Temporary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I heard that  `create table #tbname` or `create table ##tbname` creates a temporary table in temp database. However does the below query create a temp table in temp database?

```
Select * from 
(select * from table1) as temp;
```

Comment: that does not create a temporary table. It is a subquery. Chenqui.

Comment: so the data selected will be with main memory? Then CTE does the same isnt it?

Comment: this is new where did you hear it

Comment: @MuthukumarPalaniappan - I don't know what was your aim behind asking this question. That `temp` table can't be changed by you. Its a temporary result set stored by SQL server. Can you alter `temp` ?

Comment: @Borat OK, first of all I understand thats a result set from your answer. I am ok with it. next, I would like to check how it is different from CTE. I think in CTE we could create objects for the result set and can be used it multiple times. Thats the difference. I think so.

Comment: "*does the below query create a temp table?*" - plain and simple: **no**

Answer (score 2):

Some queries creates worktables in tempdb for various reasons. Using a derived table as in your example is not one of them.

If you want to have a closer look at what it does you can use `set statistics io on` and the execute the query in SSMS.

```
set statistics io on

select *
from (select * from T) as T
```

the output in the Messages tab for me is.

> Table 'T'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead
>   reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead
>   reads 0.

If you had any activity in a table in tempdb it would show there.

Another thing you can do to see if your sub-query actually changes something at all is to have a look at the query plan and perhaps compare the query plan for a query using a sub-query and one that does not.

```
select *
from (select * from T) as T

select * from T
```

The result is the same for these queries and the execution plans are identical. SQL Server saw right through your sub-query and realised that it can be simplified.

[image]

SQL is declarative a language and that means that you express what the end result should be and not how SQL Server should go about to get there.

<sup>And then there are query hints and other stuff that gives you some influence over how the optimizer generates the query plan. But that is another story.</sup>

Comment: My Lesson for Today ... SQL is declarative a language and that means that you express what the end result should be and not how SQL Server should go about to get there. +1